# Generators of a subgroup of the modular group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am looking to show the following:

If we consider the group of 2 by 2 matrices generated by $S$=$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\2 &1\end{bmatrix}$ and $T$=$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\0 &1\end{bmatrix}$, can we prove that what we get is nothing but the group of integer-entried matrices $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c &d\end{bmatrix}$ with determinant 1 such that $a$ and $d$ are odd, and $b$ and $c$ are even?

I have shown that the subgroup generated by $S$ and $T$ is contained in the group under consideration, but am not sure how to prove the opposite containment. Essentially, I need to start with a matrix $M$ in my group, which looks like: $$\begin{bmatrix}{2n+1} & 2m\\2k &{2l+1}\end{bmatrix}$$ where the determinant is 1, and $m,n,k,l$ are integers, and I need to show this can be written as a finite product of some numbers of $S$, $T$, $S^{-1}$, and $T^{-1}$s.

Can someone tell me how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to prove is not really true.

Your "group of integer-matrices $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$ with determinant $1$ such that $a$ and $d$ are odd, and $b$ and $c$ are even" is the **congruence subgroup**
$$\Gamma(2) = \ker(SL_2(\mathbb Z) \to SL_2(\mathbb Z/2)).$$

The subgroup generated by $S$ and $T$ is sometimes called the **Sanov subgroup**. As you claimed, since we clearly have $S, T \in \Gamma(2)$, the Sanov subgroup is included in $\Gamma(2)$.

The reverse inclusion is "just" false: the Sanov subgroup has index $12$ and the congruence subgroup has index $6$. You can see more details in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43726/the-free-group-f-2-has-index-12-in-sl2-mathbbz).

A great reference that you should definitely try to read is [this "blurb" by Keith Conrad](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf). The theorem 3.1 therein precisely says that $- I_2$ is basically all you need to pass from the Sanov subgroup to the congruence subgroup.